# JSON serialization abstraction in .NET Core

Tags: json, asp.net-core, .net-core

Is there a built-in type for abstracting JSON serialization in .NET Core, or AspNetCore?

I'm starting some new work and I'd like to abstract my serializer of choice so I'm not locked-in to JSON.NET forever.

Comment: `IInputFormatter` / `IOutputFormatter`?

Comment: @Yaakov Yeah okay, sort of. Not a bad answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like something is in the pipeline for .NET Core 3.0.

https://github.com/dotnet/announcements/issues/90

I'll update as details emerge.